# user will be taken to a MailChimp page, and asked to fill the subscription form again on MailChimp page in react js

Tags: reactjs, mailchimp

Actually i have 2 fields in my form, Name and Email and when user will hit the submit button this data should store into the mailchimp. but what happen is when i hit the submit button it will redirect me to the mailchimp page and ask to fill the one more Form and the i can subscribe. so i don't want user to fill that one more form on mailchimp page.

Below is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import './FormJoinWaitlist.css'
class FormJoinWaitlist extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            emailValue: '',
        fNameValue: '',
            showMessage:false
        }
    }

    handleChange=(e)=>{
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]:e.target.value
        });
        
    }

    


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="model" onClick={this.handleCloseForm}>
            <div className="JoinWaitList-model">
                <div className="JoinWaitList-content">
                  
                    <form className="JoinWaitList-form" action="https://walkingonearth.us#.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="u" value="####################"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="##########"/>
                        <h1>Join the waitlist to get early access to our app</h1>
                        <div className="JoinWaitList-form-validation">
                            <div className="formInput">
                                <label htmlFor="">Full name</label>
                                <input type="text" className="modal-input" id="FullName" name="fNameValue" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter your name" title="Full Name should be in letters only" required/>
                            </div>
                               <div className="formInput">
                                  <label htmlFor="">Email address</label>
                                  <input type="email" className="modal-input" id="Email" name="emailValue" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter your email address" required/>
                               </div>
                            
                            
                         <button type="submit" className="JoinWaitList-model-input-optipn" id="mc-embedded-subscribe">Submit</button>
                     </div>
                     {/* <!-- people should not fill these in and expect good things --> */}
                    {/* <div class="field-shift" aria-label="Please leave the following three fields empty">
                        <label for="b_name">Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="b_name" tabindex="-1" value="" placeholder="Freddie" id="b_name"/>

                        <label for="b_email">Email: </label>
                        <input type="email" name="b_email" tabindex="-1" value="" placeholder="youremail@gmail.com" id="b_email"/>

                        <label for="b_comment">Comment: </label>
                        <textarea name="b_comment" tabindex="-1" placeholder="Please comment" id="b_comment"></textarea>
                    </div> */}
                    </form>
                    {this.state.showMessage && <h5>Thank you for sign up!</h5>}
                </div>
            </div>
         
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default FormJoinWaitlist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your Form has the action of a URL, it's going to bring you TO that URL. You need to research any API's that Mailchimp has in order to be able to push that data to their servers. You'll have to implement an action that pushes the props from your form to your API Post.

Here's the link to Mailchimp's API - https://mailchimp.com/developer/

```
                   <form .. ***** THIS IS YOUR PROBLEM --> ***** action="https://walkingonearth.us#.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="u" value="####################"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="##########"/>
                        <h1>Join the waitlist to get early access to our app</h1>
                        <div className="JoinWaitList-form-validation">
                            <div className="formInput">
                                <label htmlFor="">Full name</label>
                                <input type="text" className="modal-input" id="FullName" name="fNameValue" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter your name" title="Full Name should be in letters only" required/>
                            </div>
                               <div className="formInput">
                                  <label htmlFor="">Email address</label>
                                  <input type="email" className="modal-input" id="Email" name="emailValue" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter your email address" required/>
                               </div>
                            
                            
                         <button type="submit" className="JoinWaitList-model-input-optipn" id="mc-embedded-subscribe">Submit</button>
```